# A fair die is rolled 5 times. What is the probability that there is at least two times a number out of {5,6}

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I already tried it with a binomial distribution, but are uncertain how to apply that here.

Another approach would be $1- \frac{something }{6^5}$ where the "something" is the total number of possibilities to have at least two times where the dice facing a $k \in \{ 5,6\}$ and the $6^5$ are the total possibilities of outcomes with 5 die rolls, but i have problems to get the correct "something".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a given roll giving one of those numbers is $\frac{1}{3}$. Note that the probability of this not happening at all is $\left( \frac{2}{3} \right) ^5$, and the probability of it happening once is $5 \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) ^4 \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)$. So the chance of it happening twice or more is $1$ minus the sum of the two aforementioned probabilities.

Comment: thank you very much. but to understand this better, because i am new to this: why do i have to include the probability that the event does not occur at all? and how could a combinatoric approach look like?

Comment: @vlk I’m simply computing the chance that we do not get at least 2 successful events, i.e. when there are 1 or none. This is already a combinatorial approach; there aren’t many other methods apart from this save adding all possibilities up.

Comment: thank you, that was very helpful. i understand now. :)

Answer (score 2):

As regards your second approach then "something" is equal to
$$\underbrace{4^5}_{\text{no 5 or 6}}+\underbrace{5\cdot 4^4\cdot 2}_{\text{exactly one 5 or 6}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ be the random variable. Then $P(X=4 or 5)= 2/6=1/3=p$.

You need $P(X\ge 2)=1-P(X<2)=1-P(0)-P(1)$.

and $P(X=r)=C(5,r).p^r.(1-p)^{n-r}$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: yes, thank you very much